# Updating a column in a table with values of another column in another table randomly in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I downloaded 2 SQL tables A and B from a data generator website. Suppose these 2 are linked using column std_id in both tables(std_id in A is a Primary Key and in B is a Foreign Key).

The problem is that I used UUID for generating these columns and none of std_ids in A match any std_id in B.
I was wondering how to UPDATE std_id FROM B in a random way with std_ids in A.
My query:

```
do
$$
declare
    ele record;
begin
    for ele in select std_id from B
    loop
    update A
    set std_id = (SELECT std_id FROM student OFFSET floor(random() * 100) LIMIT 1);
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

which set std_id of all records in B to a single std_id in A.

What should I do to have different std_ids in B which are selected RANDOMLY(i.e. instead of a single random std_id from A for all, I want a random std_id from A in each iteration of loop.)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `which set std_id of all records in B to a single std_id in A` but it is updating "A" so I don't see how that can be true.

Comment: You *apparent* problem - you must update the keys in the table `B` **not** in the table `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you table `A` contains 100 rows

```
create table a as
select gen_random_uuid () std_id from generate_series(1,100);
```

and yout tabel `B` contains 1000 rows

```
create table b as
select gen_random_uuid () std_id from generate_series(1,1000) t(id);
```

simple numerate each `A` rows with a unique row number (`rn`)

```
select 
row_number() over(order by std_id) rn,
std_id
from a

rn |std_id                              |
---+------------------------------------+
  1|03423be8-3da6-48b1-9bdf-a0e40ad1e502|
  2|08d45683-7816-4f57-9802-4967d5215208|
  3|0a23a421-a934-4b73-8ba3-c3a8ac502d62|
```

and assign each `B` row a randon integer between 1 and 100 (= row cont of `A`)

```
select  trunc(random() * 100 + 1)::int rn,
std_id 
from b

rn |std_id                              |
---+------------------------------------+
 10|29f925b8-1db3-4869-84b3-6b739b54850c|
 79|627ed460-6fcc-4894-8a6d-c29b708df0ec|
 75|0cfbdee6-5dce-4a5a-ab65-092886e0daeb|
```

Note that you randomly choos for each row of `B` a unique row from `A`, i.e. you define the FK relation.

Now simple join the above two subqueries on `rn` and you get a `new_std_id` taht should be updated (the `std_id` from `A`'s related record)

Query

```
with ta as (
select 
row_number() over(order by std_id) rn,
std_id
from a),
tb as (
select  trunc(random() * 100 + 1)::int rn,
std_id 
from b)
select 
tb.std_id, ta.std_id new_std_id 
from tb
join ta on tb.rn = ta.rn
order by ta.std_id::text
;

std_id                              |new_std_id                          |
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
33cad288-9b67-4585-b0d1-328381359993|03423be8-3da6-48b1-9bdf-a0e40ad1e502|
3a00c0a2-86d5-4bab-98da-02f49437c5ca|03423be8-3da6-48b1-9bdf-a0e40ad1e502|
...|
f33be20b-3b60-4da4-9e90-90a57684b4e3|03423be8-3da6-48b1-9bdf-a0e40ad1e502|
b40cb769-593a-472c-8ce2-8266683a73f1|08d45683-7816-4f57-9802-4967d5215208|
2ec2f939-55fe-4ebb-bb4b-5f2b14253638|08d45683-7816-4f57-9802-4967d5215208|
...
3204f23b-254a-4cb7-9113-874eee846f03|08d45683-7816-4f57-9802-4967d5215208|
46ee11a3-2ae2-40ee-904a-4a6e3c67a819|0a23a421-a934-4b73-8ba3-c3a8ac502d62|
```

Now you have a data prepared for the update of the table `B` using a *join update*

```
with ta as (
select 
row_number() over(order by std_id) rn,
std_id
from a),
tb as (
select  trunc(random() * 100 + 1)::int rn,
std_id 
from b),
tab as (
select 
tb.std_id, ta.std_id new_std_id
from tb
join ta on tb.rn = ta.rn
)
update b
set std_id = tab.new_std_id
from tab where b.std_id = tab.std_id
```